# jenkins how to execute perticular command based on the keyword in the git commit message?

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, git-commit, spoon

When I do a git commit, in commit message I will specify **test class name** and in junkins post-build step I am running a shell command(spoon) which needs the **class name parameter** which is in the git commit message.

I have 6 test classes depending upon the commit message perticular command should run.

example commit message :- git commit 'update [**coreTest.java**]'

command to run

```
java -jar spoon-runner-1.1.9-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
--apk example-app.apk \
--test-apk example-tests.apk
--class-name  coreTest.java
```

**coreTest.java** is the class name should be placed depending on the commit message.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to have post-receive hook on the git server side, which would:

- analyze the commit message of the git commits pushed (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8266839/6309) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870225/6309))
- [call a jenkins job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12794930/6309) (one of the 6 jobs depending of the commit message)

Answer (score 0):

try [Parametrized plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

select and pass your class name as parameter