# How to capture a git commit message in commit-msg hook?

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I wrote a script

```
#!/bin/bash
commit_msg=$1
echo "Your commit message: $commit_msg"
```

in `hooks/commit-msg` which validates the commit message in

```
git commit -m "fixed a bug"
```

But when I run the hook, I have:

```
Your commit message: .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

instead of

```
Your commit message: fixed a bug
```

How can I capture the commit message into a variable?

I've read [How to capture a git commit message and run an action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870007/how-to-capture-a-git-commit-message-and-run-an-action)
but it didn't help me because that hook was for `post-receive` and I need it for `commit-msg` so I don't have my commit message in

```
git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s
```

because my hook blocks from doing a commit.

Comment: The parameter passed into the commit-msg hook is the path to the commit message file. If you were to open the file at that path you will find the commit message.

Answer (score 11):

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks):

> The commit-msg hook takes one parameter, which again is the path to a temporary file that contains the commit message written by the developer

Therefore, you need to read *the contents of the given file* to provide the message:

```
commit_msg=$(cat "${1:?Missing commit message file}")
```